# React Native - Failed to parse declaration in styled-components

Tags: react-native, styled-components

> The same approach using stylesheet works normally

### Environment

### System:

- OS: macOS 11.6
- CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz
- Memory: 1.03 GB / 16.00 GB
- Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh

### Binaries:

- Node: 16.6.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/bin/node
- Yarn: 1.22.11 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.6.0/bin/yarn
- npm: 6.14.4 - ~/Projects/design-system/typography/node_modules/.bin/npm
- Watchman: 2021.09.13.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman

### npmPackages:

- styled-components: 5.1.0 => 5.1.0

### Reproduction

```js
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import { View } from 'react-native';

const CustomText = styled.Text(({ theme }) => ({
  fontFamily: 'Zapf Humanist 601',
}));

export default App = () => (
  <View>
    <CustomText>Your Text<CustomText>
  </View>
);
```

### Steps to reproduce

- Copy ZapfHumanist601BT-Roman.ttf in your fonts folder (./src/assets/fonts)
- Make a link font using `npx react-native link`
- Apply a linked font in your text component

### Expected Behavior

- The font is expected to be applied in the style

### Actual Behavior

`Error: Failed to parse declaration "fontFamily: Zapf Humanist 601"`

Comment: which version of react-native do you use?

Comment: as a guess, try to put your font's full name in the "fontFamily" like this: fontFamily: "ZapfHumanist601BT-Roman"

Comment: @novonimo.
I'm using the 0.65.1 version of react native, I applied the font using the full name and it works, but I would like the same behavior that occurs in Montserrat-Bold, Montserrat-Regular. Where I pass the name without the weight prefix ('Montserrat') and it works normally.
This same way works for Web, Android, IOS. Only in react native I am having this problem. Remembering that the error occurs within styled-components, with stylesheet it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

The `font-weight` property will not work fine in this situation.

You can put your fonts in `src/assets/fonts` directory:

```
src
 |_ assets 
       |_ Montserrat-Bold.ttf
       |_ Montserrat-Regular.ttf
       // and so on for the rest of fonts file
```

And define the `assets` properties in the `react-native.config.js` file which is at the root of your project in this way:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  },
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts/'],
};
```

Now, you can use the fonts in the styles like this (without define the weight property):

```
title : {
  fontFamily: Montserrat-Regular
}
```

Comment: I wasn't actually setting the weight property within the styles, I was setting the weight by the font prefix. But I understand your idea.
Example:
I want a bold font, just pass fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontWeight: 'bold'. No need to pass fontFamily: 'Montserrat-Bold'.

My context is a design-system, where font name and weight will come by tokens. So, the idea is not to worry about the weight of the font directly in its name.

Comment: I gave the example of the Montserrat font because it works the way I expect, the problem is with this Zapf font.